# Create BIGQUERY Table via GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I'm working on a Google App Script on a Google Sheet to load my sheet to BigQuery into a new table that I will create.

When I try to create a table, I get a parse error.

Here is my code:

```
function CreateTable() {

  var projectId = 'project-id-';

  var datasetId = 'testing';


  // Here is where I try to create the bqTable
  var tableId = 'test2';
  var table = {
    tableReference: {
      projectId: projectId,
      datasetId: datasetId,
      tableId: tableId,
    },
    schema: {
      fields: [
        {name: 'Id', type: 'STRING'},

      ],
    },
  };
  table = BigQuery.Tables.insert(tableId, projectId, datasetId);

}
```

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: check out your projectId - `var projectId = 'project-id-';` and extra commas

Comment: Yes That was totally it ! I didnt notice and I was stock for ours until I got this basic exemple

Comment: i can post it as an answer so you can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out your projectId - `var projectId = 'project-id-';` and extra commas

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at your code and found the bug.

Change this:

```
BigQuery.Tables.insert(tableId, projectId, datasetId);
```

To this:

```
BigQuery.Tables.insert(table, projectId, datasetId);
```